# How to merge tiff images with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, tiff

I have 4 small tiff images and I would like to generate a big one by merging the 4 single one. Does anyone know how to do it directly with Delphi or some good component that could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a command line application that can do such kind of operations on different image file formats including tiff.

The API seems to be usable from Delphi, see [PascalMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#pascal).

Comment: Oooo, this looks very nice! +1! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use GraphicEx by Mike Lischke to load the Tiff images:
http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33

Comment: Good but it doesn't seem to be able to save tiff files. It just can read them.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've never actually needed to save a tiff image so never noticed. :(

Answer (score 1):

Another excellent graphics library for Delphi is [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org)

**Edit:** As Vegar said, it looks that Graphics32 cannot be used to load TIFF format.

Comment: It's a good library, yes, but AFIK you want be able to load tiff-files with it. You would need other code, e.g. GraphicsEX, to load your graphic files.

Comment: Yeah, it looks that you are right. I used Graphics32 for jpg files, and I did not check if it supports TIFF.

Comment: And the jpg-support don't come from Graphics32, but from Delphi itself. But its still a good library :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another library you can use is [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/). It supports loading and writing of TIFF files. Beware: the Delphi wrapper is not actively maintained, but it works. We use it in our software to display previews of images.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageEn](http://www.hi-components.com/nimageen_screenshot.asp) one of the best Image libraries for Delphi, and it's native VCL ;-)